# Appearing keyboard which hides the top messages

Tags: swift, keyboard, xcode11

When the keyboard appears on view controller hiding the page top message.[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIKeyboard Suggestions height for iOS 8 notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997618/uikeyboard-suggestions-height-for-ios-8-notification)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of using textfield with keyboard

1st type

You have to declare the textfield and follows the notification observer like i did from my application.
Declare like this

```
var textField: UITextField?
```

Use this function

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
{
    //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
{
    //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
{

    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    var info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
    var contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
    if let activeFieldPresent = textField
    {
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, textField!.frame.origin))
        {
            self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(textField!.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }


}


func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
{
    var info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
    var contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false

}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!)
{
    textField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!)
{
    textField = nil
}
```

You have to declare this code in VC's Viewdidload function

```
self.textField.delegate = self
```

2nd Type

while writing the texFieldDidBeginEditing function or other wise if u havent declare the textfield while using the iboutlet then you ll be declare two things when connection to the textfields

```
Touchupinside 
TouchDidBeginEditing
```

Finally you have to give functions. Connect the delegate in storyboard
write this code.

```
 func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    {
        //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }


    func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    {
        //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
    {

        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        var info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
        var contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeFieldPresent = textField
        {
            if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, textField!.frame.origin))
            {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(textField!.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }


    }


    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        var info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
        var contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false

    }
```